# IpOverUsbSvc error

Tags: windows-phone

I have a problem with visual studio window phone 8. In the 'Windows Phone Developer Registration' window I get 'unable to connect to a phone'. The message also says 'For Windows Phone 8 phones make sure that the Windows phone IP Over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) service is running. I followed the instructions on this site and this service is running. I still get the same problem. What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

Delete devices from Device Manager as [described here](http://toddbaginski.com/blog/fixing-windows-phone-developer-registration-tool-errors/). Additionally I had to remove my Lumia devices from "Other devices". Also try to [restart IpOverUsbSvc service](http://irisclasson.com/2013/10/28/problems-and-fixes-when-registering-a-windows-phone-8-device-to-deploydebug-applications/).

Answer (score 2):

Ok first it must that your operating system and your SDK have the same language.

second check Are the date and time set correctly on the phone? In SETTINGS | date + time, turn off the Set automatically setting and then retry registration.

if the registration succeed and you have a certificate error or anything wrong then download 
the [Preview for Developers](http://www.windowsphone.com/fr-fr/store/app/preview-for-developers/178ac8a1-6519-4a0b-960c-038393741e96?signin=true) in your phone and unlock it

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using a **developer account**, not just any old Microsoft account.